# C# how to check whether int[] does not contain numbers in 1..10 or 11..20 or 21..30 and so on

Tags: c#

I'm new in C#: (cannot find out how to do it)

I have an Array `int[] draw = new int[] {3, 33, 12, 34, 15};`
and need to check, whether this array is missing numbers between: group 1-10, group 11-20, group 21-30 or group 31-40.

In case a set doesn't contain number of a group I want to increase a counter1 for 1-10 counter2 for 11-20 and so on.

How is this possible in C# ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? Even if it isn't an elegant solution?

Comment: Sort the original Array, Then pick each number from array and pick each range to test.

Comment: I would like to remind you that, we are not providing code writing services, please show us the effort

Comment: Start with a boolean for each range with an initial value of false. Then loop over the array and when you find a number inside a range, set the corresponding boolean to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
int[] draw = new int[] {3, 33, 12, 34, 15};

var group1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
var group2 = Enumerable.Range(11, 10);
var group3 = Enumerable.Range(21, 10);

int missing1 = group1.Count(i => !draw.Contains(i));
int missing2 = group2.Count(i => !draw.Contains(i));
int missing3 = group3.Count(i => !draw.Contains(i));
```

Comment: While seeing your answer and up-votes, I'm little confused that **SO started code writing services, isn't it?**

Answer (score 1):

This is simple with using GroupBy and a little module arithmetic.  The numbers can be bin into 0 to 9, 10 to 19, 20  to 29, 30 to 39.  So dividing the groups by 10 you get the number 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, .....  So if you take your numbers subtract 1 and then divide by 10 you can place the numbers into groups.  See code below

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] draw = new int[] { 3, 33, 12, 34, 15 };

            var groups = draw.GroupBy(x => (int)((x - 1) / 10)).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
            {
                if(!groups.Where(x => x.Key == i).Any())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Does not contain number between {0} and {1}", (10 * i) + 1, (10 * i) + 10);
                }

            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: Why are you casting an `int` to an `int`?

Comment: It is just a habit.  Depending on programming language some language will return a floating point number when dividing and some don't.

Comment: @jdweng Unless I am mistaken, the programming language in this instance is well known.